# Pygame: What is the Rect() arguments exactly, and what do they represent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Here is what I understand so far about Rect, it is a data type that contains all the properties of a given rectangular surface. And is used along the `pygame.draw.rect()` function as the third argument in order for it to work.

The code follows this syntax (from the official documentation):

> Rect(left, top, width, height)

I understand about the third and fourth argument, which suppose to represent the dimensions of the rectangular surface. What I don't understand is the first 2 argument - what is it suppose to represent and what does it do? Why does it always start at (0,0) and what can we use it for?

Comment: `left,top`  represent position of `left,top` corner on the screen and it means `x,y`

Comment: Can you further elaborate?

Comment: if you use `surface.get_rect()` then you get `(0,0)` because `surface` doesn't keep position, only size.

Comment: if you want to draw rect with size `(100,50)` and with `left,top` corner in position `(20,30)` then you will use `Rect(20,30,100,50)`

Comment: `Rect()` is mostly use to `blit()` image in correct place (`blit(image, rect)`), and to check collision with point - like mouse position (so you can create button) - or other Rect

Comment: `Rect()` has many fields like `left`, `rigth`, `center`, `centerx`, `centery`. If you want to draw rect with center point in (20,30) then you can use `r = Rect(0,0,100,50)` and `r.center = (20,30)` and it will recalculate `left,top` automatically.

Comment: actually nevermind, I think I now get it after doing some test. The word "left" confused me because I thought it was talking about the left side of the rectangle, and so would the top - it further confused me more that after viewing the documentation - there was an attribute called "topleft" which even confused me even more, until I realized that it was a tuple.

Comment: `left` is `x` and `x` really is on left side of rectangle - you can check 
if player touchs left border using  `player.left <= screen.left` or `player.x <= screen.x`.Or if it touchs top border `player.top <= screen.top` or `player.y <= screen.y`. BTW: `center` is tuple too, There are other tuples in Rect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two arguments get assigned to the `x` and `y` attributes of the rect, the coordinates of the topleft corner. So if you want to create a rect that is positioned at the coordinates (200, 300), you can write: `rect = pygame.Rect(200, 300, 40, 50)`. The third and fourth argument are indeed the dimensions of the resulting rect instance.

`pygame.Rect`s also have a lot of other [attributes](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) which you can use to position your rect.

```
x,y 
top, left, bottom, right 
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright 
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright 
center, centerx, centery
```

If you want to move a rect, you can assign the new position to the `x`, `y`, `topleft` or one of the other attributes.

```
rect.x = 5
rect.y = 10
# That's pretty much the same as writing:
rect.topleft = (5, 10)
# You can also increment the position.
rect.x += 5
# Or use the `rect.move_ip` method.
rect.move_ip(5, 10)
```

Rects are used to store the blit position of sprites or images and for collision detection, for example with the `colliderect` or `collidepoint` methods.